# XA context for immutant listener

Tags: clojure, hornetq, immutant

I am trying to use immutant to manage transactions across HornetQ and mysql. As I understand the docs, to do this I must use XA transactions, because I am running a standalone app and not inside an app server.

However when I try and set :xa? for the context of my application, I get exceptions when tying to setup a listener.

```
(ns example
  (:require [immutant.messaging :as msg]))

(def capture (atom nil))
(let [ctx (msg/context :host "localhost" :xa? true)
      queue (msg/queue "example" :context ctx)]
  (reset! capture nil)
  (msg/listen queue (fn [m] (reset! capture m)))
  (msg/publish queue {:my :msg}))
```

This throws "java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can't create a child context from an XA context." from the (msg/listen) invocation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi. So because I see the :host option, I'm assuming you're trying to connect to a HornetQ instance in a separate JVM: can you tell me about that JVM? Specifically which version of HornetQ it's running? Also, what version of Immutant? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've discovered a [bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/IMMUTANT-619), but in your case, I think there's a workaround: you only need that `:xa? true` option if your queue is remote. You can still create an XA transaction binding your HornetQ actions to MySQL in your listener handler using the `immutant.transactions/transaction` macro. See the [docs](http://immutant.org/documentation/2.1.4/apidoc/guide-transactions.html) for an example.

Comment: Hi Jim, in answer yo your questions above I am using HornetQ Server version 2.5.0.SNAPSHOT (Wild Hornet, 124) and in clojure space I am pulling in the [org.immutant/immutant "2.1.4"] dependency. Alas, my production use case is a remote queue, and the use of localhost in my example is just how I'm testing it locally. Thank you very much for the bug report and patch, much appreciated.